# ¿Cómo se hace la subida de ficheros a través de la api sin necesidad de una clase foto?

Tags: api

La idea sería que con un atributo imagen a través de imgur pueda subir un fichero.

Comment: Hola Ale. Tu pregunta es muy amplia. Has de explicar mejor lo que tratas de hacer y lo que has intentado. explica la tecnologia que usas y los problemas **concretos** que has tenido. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Lo primero es teniendo atributo picture y deleteHash en tu clase
Lo segundo es implementando el uploadservice que lo puedes encontrar en realstatev2.
Lo tercero poner en el package json imgur (puedes guiarte por el mismi proyecto)
Lo cuarto sudo npm install
Lo quinto implementar el metodo de subida en el controller de la clase
Lo sexto Crear un metodo en el index e modelo que implemente el del controller
Lo septimo crear en el index el metodo asignandole el del controler.

Comment: Dices: *es teniendo atributo picture y deleteHash en tu clase* ¿A qué te refieres? Podrías poner al menos un ejemplo. Luego dices *implementando el uploadservice que lo puedes encontrar en realstatev2* ¿Acaso es una librería, un framework? Podrías incluir un link a la documentación y un ejemplo de su uso. La idea al responder es generar contenido de calidad. Te invito a leer [answer]. Saludos

Comment: Buenas Juan. Gracias por responder. Sin embargo, tu respuesta parece más un comentario ya que citas como hacerlo sin detallar lo suficiente. Además, la pregunta tiene una calidad baja al no tener lo necesario para que podamos ayudarle como los intentos y el problema concreto. Ante tales preguntas, lo mejor es no responder y dejar un comentario bajo su publicacion pidiendo que la mejore (ya se que aun no tienes el privilegio de comentar). Ahora que la respuesta fue aceptada como valida, te sugiero mejorarla para que tenga los estandares de calidad e informacion que buscamos. Un saludo!